# Find the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{\cos^2 a - \cos^2 x}$ where "a" is a constant?

Tags: integration

I have tried to find the integral of the above function by dividing the numerator
 and the denominator by $(\cos x)^2$ finally and I get a part with $\log\left|\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(a)}{\tan(x)+\tan(a)}\right|$ $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but I have a trouble when I substitute $x = 0$, I get $\log|-1|$?
Can anyone explain how this happens and please tell me how to solve the integral correctly?

Comment: The integral does not converge for real $a$.

Comment: the function being integrated approaches infinity when $\cos(x)=\pm\cos(a)$.

Comment: @Maple But the integrand doesn't goes to infinity in the range of integration, moreover, the integrand is defined at 0 and pi/2, integrand is only undefined(approaches infinity) at + or - cos(a)?